# Skip DELETE FROM query in sql.j2 template when ansible variable is undefined or empty

Tags: sql, ansible, jinja2

I have a bunch of

```
DELETE FROM user_data WHERE userId = {{ my_user_id }};
```

in my sql.j2 template.

my_user_id is dynamic and might not exist at all.
When it does not exist and its value is an empty string I get

```
"Cannot execute SQL 'DELETE FROM user_data WHERE userId = ;' args [None]: (1064, \"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1\")",
```

What is the way to execute the queries so that they don't delete anything or skip just them if there is no my_user_id?

I can't skip the whole Ansible task because there are other queries in the template.

Comment: Can you please elaborate with before and after with data samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the filter *default* and test the length of the string. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_a
```

the play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          -- Start
          {% if my_user_id|default('')|length > 0 %}
          DELETE FROM user_data WHERE userId = {{ my_user_id }};
          {% endif %}
          -- End
```

will skip `DELETE FROM ...` if *my_user_id* is undefined or empty

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: |-
    -- Start
    -- End

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_a: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The SQL command will be included if *my_user_id* is not empty

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e my_user_id=12

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: |-
    -- Start
    DELETE FROM user_data WHERE userId = 12;
    -- End

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_a: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Use the *if* condition in your template.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know I could use jinja2 conditionals in sql.j2 templates